# Lucee- invalid component definition for custom tag

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm working on a Lucee application that makes heavy use of custom tags.

My structure is as follows:

Calling app file - `C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\web-portal\web-champs\index.cfm`

Location of file I'm calling - `C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\empportal\Champs\CFC\invoice.cfc`

I've defined a custom tag in the Lucee admin with a name of `empportal` and resource of `C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\empportal\` (also tried without a trailing `\`). I restarted the server after adding the custom tag.

Error message

> invalid component definition, can't find component [empportal.Champs.CFC.invoice]
> Stacktrace
> The Error Occurred in
> C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\web-portal\web-champs\dsp_outstandingInvoices.cfm: line 1
> `1: <cfinvoke component="empportal.Champs.CFC.invoice" method="getOutstandingItems" org_ID="#session.orgID#" returnvariable="getOutstandingItems" />`

I also tried creating the component using `new empportal.Champs.CFC.invoice()` and same issue.

Comment: I noticed that the error message has a dash in the component name `emp-portal` but the code referenced does not `empportal`.  Can you find where you might be referencing `emp-portal` in the code and fix that?

Comment: That's not the issue, I replaced some sensitive information and updated that place incorrectly. Will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lucee you need to place files in the `ROOT\` folder so tomcat can load them. In my case moving the folders to `C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\` instead of `C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\` and restarting fixed the issue.

Comment: As an aside, the Lucee admin has separate admin settings to add Custom Tag archives, `<cf_` and Component archives (CFCs).